# DOM with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm newbie to web programming and I can't understand why the following code doesn't work.

It is supposed to remove permanently the content of the div element when the button is pressed, but it disappears for a while and then reappears.

The code is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function prueba(){
            document.getElementById('uno').innerHTML="";
        }
    </script>

    <div id="uno">CONTENEDOR UNO</div>
    <form onSubmit="prueba()">
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your page is simply reloading. You're doing nothing to stop the submit event of your form.

Comment: The form submits and the page reloads.

Comment: It will re-appear when you refresh the page and it is supposed to work that way... The hide will work till the page is refreshed as the default state of that DIV to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what's happening is that your button is submitting a form, which sends the form to the web server then reloads your page. So:

1. Your "onSubmit" JS runs immediately and clears the div content.
2. Your page reloads and the content comes back.

Try something like this instead of a form (i.e. remove the surrounding form tag):

```
<button onclick="prueba()">Entrar</button>
```

Comment: I simplified the code but I have more inputs in the form so I need it. There is any way to do what I want with the form and the onSubmit?

Comment: Are you sure you need the data going up to the server, rather than just running client-side code in JavaScript? If so, your page is going to be rendered again, so what you need to do is deliver the "CONTENEDOR UNO" content dynamically from your server, rather than hardcoding it into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't need a form to hide a `DIV`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function prueba(){
            document.getElementById('uno').innerHTML="";
        }
    </script>

    <div id="uno">CONTENEDOR UNO</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="prueba()" value="Entrar">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/36pvts4t/2/
try this , for me this is working .This code is remove the text in div with id "uno" , on form submit .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function prueba(){
            console.log("Inside the function preueba ");
            document.getElementById('uno').innerHTML="";
        }
    </script>

    <div id="uno">CONTENEDOR UNO</div>

    <form action="#" method="get" onSubmit="prueba()" target="_blank" >
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```